# How do you enable 'require(*/*.vrx)' using rn-cli.config?

Tags: react-native, augmented-reality, metro-bundler, viro-react

The Metro bundler for react-native cli is unable to resolve a **.vrx** file (used for a viroreact AR scene).

I've tried to create an rn-cli.config.js file in the project root that should have sorted it but it isn't. What am I missing?

I've tried to create an rn-cli.config.js file in the project root that should have sorted it but it isn't. What am I missing?

The path specified is definitely correct in the requiring .js

**rn-cli.config.js**

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: { assetExts }
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: [...assetExts, "obj", "mtl", "JPG", "vrx", "fbx", "hdr"]
    }
  };
})();
```

Metro bundler reporting this error

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./js/res/coffee_mug/object_coffee_mug.vrx` from `C:\Users\Dave\Documents\schoolOfCode\Final Project\final-project-app-brumgo-front-end\components\ARtest\index.js`: The module `./js/res/coffee_mug/object_coffee_mug.vrx` could not be found from `C:\Users\Dave\Documents\schoolOfCode\Final Project\final-project-app-brumgo-front-end\components\ARtest\index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Comment: can you check if this link helps: 

https://github.com/viromedia/viro/issues/509#issuecomment-454492692

Answer (score 0):

Please update the metro.config.js at the root of your project as follows.

```
const {getDefaultConfig} = require('metro-config');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig();

  return {
    resolver: {
      assetExts: [
        ...assetExts,
        'obj',
        'mtl',
        'JPG',
        'vrx',
        'hdr',
        'gltf',
        'glb',
        'bin',
        'arobject',
        'gif',
      ],
    },
  };
})();
```